# My Json array only returns the last array. How to fix that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a problem with my JSON array. This is my Ajax code (I upload file excel and return it to JSON. Then convert Json to string and save to myDb):

```
function exportExcelToTable() {
    $('#upload-excel-convert').change(function (e) {
        let file = $(this).prop('files')[0];
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file",file);
        $("#js-render-btn-see-excel").html('');
        $('#js-table-excel tbody').html('');
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url: '/order/excel/read-file',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType:'json',
            success(data) {
                let $data = $('input[name="order[sizeFile]"]');

                for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $data.val(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
                    console.log(data[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    })
}
```

This's Json `console.log(data[i])` to return.

```
[["XS ", "Nam", null, null, null, 20],
 ["S", null, 13, null, null, 35],
 ["M", null, 12, null, null, 12]
]
```

And my input value just return last Array

```
<input type="hidden" name="order[sizeFile]" value="["M";,null,12,null,null,12]">
```

I want the input value like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="order[sizeFile]" value="[["XS ", "Nam", null, null, null, 20],["S", null, 13, null, null, 35],["M", null, 12, null, null, 12]]">
```

How to I fix that? Thank you.

`P/s` Sorry about my English.

`UPDATE`
I was updating my code.

```
function exportExcelToTable() {
    $('#upload-excel-convert').change(function (e) {
        let file = $(this).prop('files')[0];
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file",file);
        $("#js-render-btn-see-excel").html('');
        $('#js-table-excel tbody').html('');
        $.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url: '/order/excel/read-file',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType:'json',
            success(data) {
                let $data = $('input[name="order[sizeFile]"]');
                let list;

                for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                    list += JSON.stringify(data[i]);
                    $data.val(list);
                    console.log(data[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    })
}
```

It's correct, But my input show `undefined` on value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="order[sizeFile]" value="undefined[["XS ", "Nam", null, null, null, 20],["S", null, 13, null, null, 35],["M", null, 12, null, null, 12]]">
```

Comment: is this what you want ? 

<input type="hidden" name="order[sizeFile]" value="[["XS ", "Nam", null, null, null, 20],["S", null, 13, null, null, 35],["M", null, 12, null, null, 12]]">

Comment: JS arrays are 0-based.

Comment: @sid Yes. That's what I wan't. :))

Comment: I changed `let i = 0`. But it's till the same. @DaveNewton

Comment: Try building your string *then* setting the `val` instead of setting it each time through the loop.

Comment: But I don't wan't get the first array. Cuz my excel exactly return `[["Size ", "Sex","Number", "Name", "Phone", "Quantity"],["XS ", "Nam", null, null, null, 20],["S", null, 13, null, null, 35],["M", null, 12, null, null, 12]]`. And first array just a title. I don't want it in my databsae.

Answer (score 0):

Store the output of the console's in a var and then inside the success callback, you can use that array and replace the value on the input

Your JS should be

```
success(data) {
    let $data = $('input[name="order[sizeFile]"]');


    var excelData = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        $data.val(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
        console.log(data[i]);
        excelData.push(data[i])
    }

    $("#showValues").val(excelData);

}
```

and give an id to the input field to be able to replace the value later

```
<input type="hidden" id="showValues" name="order[sizeFile]" value="">
```

Comment: Yeah. It's works. But how to my input exactly like `[["XS ", "Nam", null, null, null, 20],["S", null, 13, null, null, 35],["M", null, 12, null, null, 12]]`? :))

Comment: what does excelData say ?

Comment: I change your code to `excelData.push(JSON.stringify(data[i]))`. And just give me `["XS ", "Nam", null, null, null, 20],["S", null, 13, null, null, 35],["M", null, 12, null, null, 12]`

Comment: I did it. I just add `'['+excelData+']'`. Thank you so much.